# Requiring an external dependency for a Swift binary framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am in the process of building a set of SDK frameworks for use in my organization.
There is a core framework for user authentication `Auth` and another framework `B` that relies on it for user information. Framework `B` is optional.

How am I supposed to setup a Workspace and project target for `B`, so that

1. `Auth` is not embedded with `B`, but available during development
2. `B` uses `Auth` as an external dependency that needs to be present in whatever project it is embedded in

In the end I want to use xcframeworks and distribute over SwiftPM packages.

Currently I have a Project for `B` with targets for the framework and a `Demo` application.
The framework target includes `Auth` under **Framework & Libraries** as **Do Not Embed** and the Demo's **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content** Section imports `Auth` and `B` as **Embed & Sign**.

This works on simulator, but running the Demo on device throws the following errors:

1. `No such module 'Auth'` on the `import Auth` line in code in `B`
2. `Missing required module 'Auth'` on the import `B` line in code in the Demo application

Is there any way to make `B` find the framework inside the project it's imported in as an external dependency?
Would this be easier to do with SwiftPM (just wait for Swift 5.3 and support for binary artifacts)?

I came across this document https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-PROJ_CONFIG-APPS_WITH_DEPENDENCIES_BETWEEN_FRAMEWORKS which kind of states that I'm on the right way:

> The app target is responsible for embedding all of the frameworks, including any frameworks that other frameworks depend on

Comment: Yes, use SwiftPM. Even now, you could just depend on the source and build.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention this explicitly, but both `Auth` and `B` are supposed to be binary frameworks